# Function return a tuple made of vectors

Tags: c++, function, c++11, tuples

I am trying avoid output arguments in my functions. The old function is:

```
void getAllBlockMeanError(
    const vector<int> &vec, vector<int> &fact, vector<int> &mean, vector<int> &err)
```

Here `vec` is input argument, `fact`, `mean` and `err` are output argument. I tried to group output argument to one tuple:

```
tuple< vector<int>, vector<int>, vector<int> > 
                                  getAllBlockMeanErrorTuple(const vector<int> &vec)
{
    vector<int> fact, mean, err;
    //....
    return make_tuple(fact, mean, err);
}
```

Now I can call the new function with:

```
tie(fact, mean, err) = getAllBlockMeanErrorTuple(vec);
```

It looks cleaner to me. While I have a question, how does equal assignment of `tie(fact, mean, err)` work? Does it do a deep copy or a move? Since `fact`, `mean` and `err` inside `getAllBlockMeanErrorTuple` will be destroyed, I hope it is doing a move instead of a deep copy.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think as written it will copy the vectors. If you move the vectors into `make_tuple()`, then they should be moved.

Comment: I would use a `struct Result { vector<int> fact; vector<int> mean; vector<int> err; };` instead of tuple to have better naming for getter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You function signature is `tuple< vector<int>, vector<int>, vector<int> >`, which is a temporary and the elements are eligible to be moved, so

```
std::tie(fact, mean, err) = getAllBlockMeanErrorTuple(vec)
```

should move-assign `fact`, `mean`, and `err`.

Here's a sample program for you to see for yourself ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e71fabef0a6a816)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

struct A
{
    A() = default;
    ~A() = default;
    A(const A&)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy ctor\n";
    }
    A(A&&)
    {
        std::cout << "Move ctor\n";
    }
    A& operator=(const A&)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy assign\n";
        return *this;
    }
    A& operator=(A&&)
    {
        std::cout << "Move assign\n";
        return *this;
    }
};

std::tuple<A, A> DoTheThing()
{
    A first;
    A second;
    return std::make_tuple(first, second);
}

int main()
{
    A first;
    A second;
    std::tie(first, second) = DoTheThing();
}
```

Output:

> Copy ctor 
>   Copy ctor
>   Move assign
>   Move assign

Note that the function had to create copies of the vectors for returning the `tuple`, which may not be what you want. You may want to `std::move` the elements into `std::make_tuple`:

```
return make_tuple(std::move(fact), std::move(mean), std::move(err));
```

[Here's the same example as above, but with std::move used in `make_tuple`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/741dc1a213ad379f)

Note that with C++17's Structured Bindings, you can forget about using `std::tie` at all, and lean more on `auto` (Thanks, @Yakk):

```
auto[fact, mean, err] = getAllBlockMeanErrorTuple(vec);
```

The early implementations of the C++17 standard for clang (3.8.0) and gcc (6.1.0) don't support it yet, however it seems there is some support in clang 4.0.0: [Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ruvwDNTDQNvSg5YO) (Thanks, @Revolver_Ocelot)

You'll notice that the output with structured bindings changes to:

> Move ctor 
>   Move ctor

Indicating that they take advantage of copy-elision, which saves additional move operations.

Comment: `auto[fact, mean, err] = getAllBlockMeanErrorTuple(vec);`

Comment: @Yakk: Isn't that C++17?

Comment: Yes, but I would argue worth mentioning, at least in passing.

Comment: clang 4 has limited support for structured bindings: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/SAns8Kzsz9FgSmzt

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: Thank you very much. Post updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helps.

Answer (score 12):

```
std::tie(fact, mean, err) = getAllBlockMeanErrorTuple(vec);
```

would do a move assignment.

But as mentioned in comment

```
return make_tuple(fact, mean, err);
```

would do a copy, you may solve that with:

```
return make_tuple(std::move(fact), std::move(mean), std::move(err));
```

Comment: At least mention C++17 structured bindings!  We are mere months away from it being here!  (for limited values of here)

Comment: Thank you Jarod42.